# MS Access 2007 database in asp.net(Make it work on hosting)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, hosting

I have a web application(c# asp.net) and successfully uploaded it to hosting. It works good, but doesn't connect to a database(MS Access 2007). I've put the database in `App_Data` folder and typed a ConnectionString like this

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+Server.MapPath("App_Data\\WebSiteDatabase.accdb");
con.Open();
```

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: use "~\App_Data\\..." or, instead, do not use Server.MapPath in favor of the "|DataDirectory|" syntax.

Comment: Is hosting server contains `MS-Access` installed ?

Comment: Hmmm. I tryed but it didn't help. btw I used somee.com

Comment: What Adriano gave you is the right advise, but it all depends on your hosting provider try to confirm it with their tech whether they support MS access DB or not.